# How to create a custom role on service Strapi starts up?

Tags: strapi

As a strapi user I want to create a custom Role for the authentificated users, i know that i can write code on boostrap function in `/src/api/server.js` and used it for fill entities with default values but i want also to create a Custom Role (but not use admin UI interface) and didnt find any clear information how to do that. For version 3 I found some information about this but it didn't work as i noticed in actual version.

Already tried example below but it give me an `Error: Model role not found`

```
const authenticatedRoleExists = strapi.query('role', 'strapi-admin').findOne();
const authenticatedRole = strapi.query('role', 'strapi-admin').create({
      name: 'MyRole',
      code: 'authenticated',
      description: 'Authenticated User Role'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add this as your need basis in ./config/functions/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports = async () => {
  // Check if the custom role already exists
  const roleExists = await strapi.query('role', 'users-permissions').findOne({ type: 'custom', name: 'YourRoleName' });

  // Create the custom role if it doesn't exist
  if (!roleExists) {
    await strapi.query('role', 'users-permissions').create({
      name: 'YourRoleName',
      type: 'custom',
      description: 'Your role description',
      permissions: [
        {
          action: 'plugin::content-manager.explorer.create',
          subject: 'YourContentType',
        },
        // Add more permissions as needed
      ],
    });
  }
};
```

Replace 'YourRoleName' with the name of your custom role. Replace 'YourContentType' with the name of the content type for which you want to grant permissions.